# list of all kind sql exceptions

Tags: c#, exception, translation, sqlexception

How can i gets the name of all SQL exceptions? For handling them in my project? Thanks.

Comment: How do you intend to "handle" the exceptions? Do you plan to fix what's wrong? You will likely be better off not handling the exceptions at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you mean error number. 
You can get a list of numbers and their descriptions [there](http://vista.intersystems.com/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=RSQL_sqlerrors). 
However it may not be complete, because different databases may use some additional codes as well.

So in your case you may want to catch SqlException, get its error collection (SqlErrorCollection) and check for Number property in every SqlError of this collection.

**UPD:**
Since you want to translate the error, I think it is better to look for severities ([SqlException.Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception.class.aspx) property) and if you are using MS SQL you can look up that severity in SYSMESSAGES database, it looks that there may be translation already for your language.

Comment: You may also want to take a look at this article (http://www.developer.com/tech/article.php/724711/Microsoft-SQL-Server-2000-Error-Messages.htm). It explains in general ranges of most common sql errors.

Comment: Perfect example of why one should summaries a link instead of just linking, the link is now broken.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one exception type in the `System.Data.SqlClient` namespace, and that's `SqlException`.

Comment: i know this.i mean for example format exception,null refrence exception,or... that maybe occured.

Comment: @John Saunders:my first language is persian and i want to show Suitable message in persian,considering the exception details.

Comment: @na.fa: `FormatException` and `NullReferenceException` have absolutely nothing to do with SQL.